# Defer report execution until after parameters are chosen

Tags: reporting-services

The first time a parametrized reporting services report is called it is automatically executed with the default parameters which takes too long.

Is there a way to prevent the report from being executed until the "View Report" button is clicked when the correct and more restrictive parameters will be already chosen?

Answer (score 0):

The report will not automatically execute if you set one or more parameters' default value to NULL.  Given this, and the fact that you've stated your report takes too long to execute with your default values, I'd recommend omitting the default values for your parameters.  Set the default values to null and let the user make their selections at run-time.

Comment: Indeed all parameters default values except one are set to null.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set them all to null?

Comment: They were all null before and the execution time was much worse so I had to set one to a certain value to make the first time execution bearable.